# How do I return the result of a SELECT COUNT statement as a string in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm wondering how to return the result from a SELECT COUNT statement in C#.

I have a sql statement that returns the count of 15.

Currently, I'm returning the datareader. Can I somehow return the result of that as a string?

```
    static public SqlDataReader FillDataReader(string sql, SqlParameter[] parms)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    SqlDataReader dr = null;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 120; //120 seconds for the query to finish executing

    foreach (SqlParameter p in parms)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
    }
    try
    {
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        if (dr != null)
        {
            dr.Close();
        }
        conn.Close();


        //DBUtilExceptionHandler(ex, sql);

        throw ex;


    }
    finally
    {
    }

    return dr; //This could be null...be sure to test for that when you use it

}
```

Or I could use a different method. I just don't know what it should be.

Any help is appreciated.

This is my select statement:

```
        select count(LeadListID) from LeadLists WHERE SalesPersonID = 1
AND LeadListDateCreated BETWEEN '9/1/11' AND '10/1/11 23:59:59'
```

Comment: You are looking for ExecuteScalar instead of ExecuteReader

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sure - just use:

```
int count = (int) query.ExecuteScalar();
// TODO: Decide the right culture to use etc
return count.ToString();
```

Notes:

- Use `using` statements instead of manual try/catch/finally blocks
- You should close the connection *whether or not there was an error*
- Given that the natural result of the query is an integer, I would change it to return an `int`, not a `string`. Let the caller make that conversion if they want to
- If there's an error, you should almost certainly let the exception bubble up, rather than returning `null`

I would write the code as:

```
public static int ExecuteScalarInt32(string sql, SqlParameter[] parms)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn) { Parameters = parms })
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.CommandTimeout = 120;
        return (int) command.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

If you *really* needed a version to work on an arbitrary data reader, you could write it as:

```
public static T ExecuteQuery<T>(string sql, SqlParameter[] parms,
                                Func<SqlDataReader, T> projection)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn) { Parameters = parms })
    {
        conn.Open();
        command.CommandTimeout = 120;
        return projection(command.ExecuteReader());
    }
}
```

And then call it with:

```
int count = ExecuteQuery<int>(sql, parms, reader => {
                                  if (!reader.MoveNext()) {
                                      throw new SomeGoodExceptionType("No data");
                                  }
                                  return reader.GetInt32(0);
                              });
```

Comment: Hi Jon, This is great. I'm new to this. What SqlParameter gets passed into the method?

Comment: @Barrett: Um, I don't know - whatever you were doing before. I assumed you already knew that side of things, given that it's in your original code.

Comment: I suppose I don't need to pass any parameters because that's all taken care of in my select statement.

Comment: @Barrett: In that case pass in an empty array (or remove the ability to pass in parameters completely, if you don't need it elsewhere either).

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can always call the `ToString()` method in .NET on the single field when reading it:

```
dr[0].ToString()
```

Are there many records that you want to concat as a string?  Then you loop through each row, grab the value as a string, and create a master string in a for loop fashion.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're expecting only a single value, a better alternative to `ExecuteReader` is the [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx) method:

```cs
try
{
    var count = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either cast it as a varchar in your sql:

```
select cast(count(LeadListID) as varchar(10))
from LeadLists 
WHERE SalesPersonID = 1
AND LeadListDateCreated BETWEEN '9/1/11' AND '10/1/11 23:59:59'
```

or just call .ToString() on the result, as shown in other answers.

Additionally, I'm not a fan of relying on `CommandBehavior.CloseConnection` for DataReaders. I much prefer code like this:

```
static public IEnumerable<IDataRecord> GetDataReader(string sql, SqlParameter[] parms)
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandTimeout = 120; //120 seconds for the query to finish executing

        foreach (SqlParameter p in parms)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
        }

        conn.Open();
        using (var dr= cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                yield return dr;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use ExecuteScalar instead, that will return the first field from the first record of the returned recordset, which is what you want.  That will return to you an object that is really an integer.  Add a ToString to that and you should be good.